# Swift - cell table view with a horizontal stack view inside contains different texts - automatic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I'm programming an app for iOS in swift and I have a problem with a table view. the cell of this table have a horizontal stackView inside with three label containing text of different lengths. I have already put all the constraints and it seems work to autoresize the height of the cell but I realize something: it autoresize the height of the cell according to the shortest one. So it truncate the longer one as you can see in the image. please help I don't know how to fix it and I couldn't find a solution online.

How to set cell height according to cell component height.
[image problem: at verse 8 it truncate according the shortest one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bS3R.jpg)

Comment: what constraints do you give to the lbls ?? , can you share a demo ??

Comment: One possible way is to **declare a label in your view controller**. Inside the method that calculate the height of the `UITableCell`, calculate the height for 3 of the texts blocks by setting these texts to the label. Then return the max height you obtained. If you don't know how to calculate the dynamic CGSize of UILabel or some UI elements, read about `sizeToFit()` and `sizeThatFit(_:)` methods.

Comment: Set the compression resistance of all the labels higher than the priority of your stackview's bottom constraint.

Answer (score 0):

`Auto Layout` the `Horizontal StackView` in the `UITableViewCell`. ie, add the leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints to the cell `ContentView`. Set the `numberOfLines` of all the `UILabel`s to 0 in `IdentityInspector` or in code.

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Add the following `UITableView Delegate` methods to configure the cell height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

It will automatically size all your cells to the required height which is the maximum height among the three labels to display the whole text in each.

Use `sizeToFit()` to adjust the vertical alignment of labels. To make the text vertically aligned to top left (which is obviously done by modifying the frame of labels - shrinking a label just to contain the text).

```
cell.labelOne.sizeToFit()
cell.labelTwo.sizeToFit()
cell.labelThree.sizeToFit()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```